# How do I activate/use JIT-Debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, monogame, jit

I made a game with monogame (version 3.7.1) in C# and tried to publish it in Visual Studio 2017. The publishing worked fine but after that, I tried to execute the setup.exe file but unfortunately, I get a NullReferenceException the problem is I don't know how to debug and find out what's causing the error.

At the end, it states you can activate debugging by activating JIT-Debugging. I already have done that by writing the line:

> < system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />

Into the machine.config file under the configuration, but now I don't know how to use it because when I run the .exe it stills gives me the NullReferenceException error and I didn't find any clue on the internet how to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure that JIT will apply to running the setup.exe, it only applies to actual code that you've written and are running. To use JIT you'd have to attach to the process in Visual Studio and ensure it's compiled in debug mode with symbols.

Comment: Hi brachi, to enable the JIT debugging, please run the VS as administrator and go to Tools-Options-Debugging-Just-In-Time, select the options to save, please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger?view=vs-2017 and Just-In-Time debugging works for Windows desktop apps. It does not work for Universal Windows Apps, or for managed code that is hosted in a native application, such as Visualizers.

Answer (score 0):

The steps for setting up the JIT debugger in VS are over at:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger?view=vs-2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)

The JIT debugger will pop for any unhandled .NET exception in any .NET app. Of course to debug an app you will need to have source and symbols, and debugging retail/release bits is more difficult.