# Is there a way to "debug" a real website (for example stackoverflow) INSIDE VSCode like you can inside chrome devtools?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, web-development-server

So I would like to study websites and their code, do some changes - locally ofcourse (to learn). I know how to do it using chrome devtools - but I really like using vscode. Because live server is only for your local project, not one with the url. Even if I force the server to open a specific url, I can't edit it in vscode (I mean, not counting the devtools extension - because, its basically the same.

Even if I copy the css files in a folder, vscode does detect the file and opens it, but editing doesn't have an effect on the website.

Comment: the only options are if you are a developer on the team of a specific site or if their code if freely available on github (or similar) and you clone the repo

Comment: no way chrome devtools is able to debug my backend

Comment: you could use Visual Studio Community to debug web application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943944/how-do-i-activate-use-jit-debugging

Comment: @rioV8 i was talking about front-end. should be more specific about that.